# Representing Complex JSON using Salat and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, salat

I have a case class composition that looks like below:

```
case class TypeA(id: Int, text: String, typeBList: List[TypeB])
case class TypeB(id: Int, text: String)
```

I use MongoDB for persisting the data and the resulting JSON document looks like:

```
TypeA {
  id: 101,
  text: "This is of type A",
  typeBList: [
    {id: 1001, text: "First TypeB text"},
    {id: 1002, text: "Second TypeB text"}
  ]
}
```

How can I represent my SalatDAO that would help me use it's API and box the results of the find operation to the respective types? Is it automagically done or should I use some annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salat author here.  If TypeB is actually a type hierarchy, you need to annotate it with `@Salat` - otherwise, you don't need to do anything special.

If you need help, feel free to make a small sample project on Github and I will be happy to fork and fix it so you can have a working example.